# In a spinning spacecraft, the astronaut lets out of a mass attached to a string from a window, what happens to the mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

The spacecraft is a cylinder spinning about its cylindrical axis. A mass attached to a long string is slowly let out from the side of the cylinder. Why does it start to perform simple harmonic motion?

Comment: What would you expect to happen instead?